# Will my SQL Server query be faster if I use a bigint in place of time in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I store my times as a `bigint` in the database (08:30:1234 = 8301234) would those be faster to query than just storing a `time`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the results are unlikely to be different - if anything since [`BIGINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) is 8 bytes and [`TIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) is 5 bytes, `TIME` is more likely to perform.

If your queries are slow, you need to check your indexing strategy and work according the the query plans.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still designing the database and the old table was using a BIGINT in place of TIME. I wasn't sure if it was for query speed but now it sounds like it was there because MSSQL 2005 only had DateTime.

Comment: @Stephen - very likely, though it could have used `DateTime` for that (it is also 8 bytes) which would have conserved meaning, then simply ignore the date component.

Comment: I think using a number to represent a date or time is solving the wrong problem and creating others. For example, you miss out on validation, datediff/dateadd rules and other built-in date-related functionality.